# How to prevent hair curves from flickering

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

so I have this vest that I've added hair curves to (ie geometry nodes) and I liked how quickly I was able to get the look that I wanted. However, after making a test render of the full animation, I realized that the hair is constantly changing and moving around, creating a flickering effect.

I've tried following a section from this tutorial that touched on this issue (https://youtu.be/9NM9oaijmLg?si=3suoXk--aKcWk7Yu&t=598): I added a Store Named Attribute node (+ a Position node connected to the value socket) right after the first node, then a Set Position (+ Named attribute) at the end of the chain, before join geometry. This only seemed to the hair settings I'd implemented (waviness, clumping).

I'm just not really sure where in the chain I should be adding these nodes, since the hair curve geo node setup is very different from the one in the tutorial. Should I be using a different approach altogether?

Comment: send pictures please (of the nodes, result, and desired results)

Comment: I messed around with the settings some more today, and did a full reset. This time I only added base hair curves, Clump Hair, and Curl Hair (from the assets library). This time I did not use Shrinkwrap Hair curves (I originally used this because the hair was appearing on both sides of the mesh instead of only the outside). The hair has stopped flickering. I suspect the Shrinkwrap node tree was responsible for this behaviour.